# Bold claim environment through local layout in LyX

Tags: lyx, theorems, lyx-layouts

I would like to create a new bold "Afirmação" ("Claim" in portuguese) environment through "Local Layout" in LyX (I don't want to create a new layout file). So I went to Document -> Settings -> Local Layout and copied the following code:

```
Style AfirmaçãoBold
CopyStyle             Theorem
LatexName             afirmacao
LabelString           "Afirmação \theafirmacao."
Preamble
  \theoremstyle{plain}
  \newtheorem{afirmacao}[thm]{\protect\afirmacaoname}
EndPreamble
LangPreamble
  \providecommand{\afirmacaoname}{_(Afirmação)}
EndLangPreamble
BabelPreamble
  \addto\captions$$lang{\renewcommand{\afirmacaoname}{_(Afirmação)}}
EndBabelPreamble
End
```

I got the environment formatted the way I wanted, but the enumeration is not right. I am using  "Theorems (AMS, numbered by type)" and "Theorems (AMS-extended, numbered by type)" modules. This is what I got:

[image: Output]

This is the first "AfirmaçãoBold" environment in the document, but I got it numbered 3. Maybe this has something to do with the fact that the numbered environment before it is a "Lemma 3". How can I make an independent numbering for it, so it can start from 1? Also, how can I get the option to use "AfirmaçãoBold*", that is, how can I have the option not to number it at all? (I would like to have both options to choose). Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
 \newtheorem{afirmacao}[thm]{\protect\afirmacaoname}
```

It means, that it should be numbered with `thm`. Removing `[thm]` should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the enumeration problem. Now, do you know how can I have the option to use the "AfirmaçãoBold*" environment?